# Git filter-branch says "no such file" but ls says otherwise?

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu-12.04

I've accidentally committed a file, `local.py`, with password information in.

I've tried to use filter-branch to remove the file but I'm told the file doesn't exist. `ls` says otherwise . I'm sure this is simple but can someone explain why ?

Here's `ls` confirming the file exists.

```
(spsp)user99@jaffa:~/dev/antibes$ ls -l ferrat_project/ferrat_project/settings/local.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user99 user99 458 Sep  5 10:44 ferrat_project/ferrat_project/settings/local.py
```

And here's `git filter-branch` failing because it can't find the file.

```
(spsp)user99@jaffa:~/dev/antibes$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git rm ferrat_project/ferrat_project/settings/local.py' HEAD
Rewrite 123454323asdj157f2cf6a83e6f2777e85da5b0b (1/52)rm: cannot remove ‘ferrat_project/ferrat_project/settings/local.py’: No such file or directory
tree filter failed: git rm ferrat_project/ferrat_project/settings/local.py
```

---

**EDIT 1: Answering some questions posed in comments.**

*Did the file exist at the revision in that error message?*

The  revision referenced is the first commit to the repository. The file did not exist at that point.

*When did you add this file?*

The file was added (by accident) in the third commit to the repository. There are 52 commits in the repository.

---

**EDIT 2: Something I tried in response to comments.**
I re-read the filter-branch man page subsequently tried this :

```
user99@jaffa:~/dev/antibes$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f ferrat/ferrat/settings/local.py' HEAD
Rewrite 002198729d953ee70a63f2ed68011b3ffb165043 (52/52)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
```

Which at least worked but which, of course, actually deleted the file I was trying to hide. I wasn't too worried about this as I had taken a backup before I started so I then made an edit to .gitignore to stop local.py reappearing and then copied local.py from my backup and ... as far as I can tell ... all is now well.

I'm pretty sure I should have used 'git rm' instead of 'rm' and perhaps there were other things I've done wrong but this does at least seems to have worked.

Comment: Did the file exist at the revision in that error message? Presumably not. The git filter-branch man page talks about this in one of its examples. That being said. When did you add this file? Just now?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am about to make edits to the question to answer your questions.

Comment: Just following up on your comment Etan I read, again, the filter-branch man page and I seem to have resolved the issue (although) I'm not 100% sure. About to edit the question with more details.